# How to read a text file using Relative path in scala

Tags: scala, maven

I have a simple mvn project written in scala. I want to access a text file and read its content. The code is working fine but the only issue is I am giving the absolute path when reading the text file. Following is the directory structure of my project.

How can I use the relative path to read that file? 
(Do I have to move the movies.txt file in to the resources directory, if so still how would I read that file?)

Any insight will be much appreciated. Thank you

```
myproject
|-src
|  |-resources
|  |-scala
|      |-movies.simulator
|           |-Boot
|           |-Simulate
|                |-myobject.scala
|                      |Simulate
|
|-target
|-pom.xml
|-README
|-movies.txt
```

In the myobject.scala where the Simulate is the package object, I access the movies.txt file using the absolute path.

```
import scala.io.Source
Source
    .fromFile("/home/eshan/projecs/myproject/movies.txt")
    .getLines
    .foreach { line =>
    count+=1
      // custom code            
}
```

Comment: [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#osrelpath) is the best modern solution, see my answer for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move your `movies.txt` to `resources` dir, then you can do the following:

```
val f = new File(getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("movies.txt").getPath)

import scala.io.Source
Source
    .fromFile(f)
    .getLines
    .foreach { line =>
    count+=1
      // custom code            
}
```

Comment: Hello, I suppose this will work. I am getting an unrelated error of movies.txt file not being found in target/myproject/lib. Once I fix it I believe your solution will work. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I had to change the .txt to .conf. (to fix the unrelated issue). Then your solution worked for the movies.conf with the addition of the "import java.io.File" to my scala code. Thanks

Comment: i am getting error `reference to getClass is ambiguous; it is both defined in class Object and imported subsequently by import sparkSession.implicits._` when I am trying to use your approach, but don't understand why? any idea ?

Comment: @Andrey... just use `this.getClass` instead of just `getClass`

Answer (score 5):

More concisely you can use:

```
Source.fromResource("movies.txt")
```

which will look for a path relative to the resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

[os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#osread) is the best way to read files with Scala.

```
os.read(os.pwd/"movies.txt")
```

os-lib also [supports relative paths](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib#osrelpath) but those shouldn't be needed here.

This lib makes it easy to read files, construct paths, and other filesystem operations, see [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more details.

Comment: This library helped me. Thanks. Remember when using os.pwd and the folder is deeper in the filesystem you will need to use "segment" for example: os.pwd/"jsonFolder"/"guitarFolder"/"guitar.json"