# Scala: FileNotFoundException when the file does exist

Tags: scala

I started learning Scala a few weeks ago and I am now trying to read data from a .csv file.

However, the line `val data = fromFile("test.csv")` returns me the error 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.csv (No such file or directory)`

Usually, this error happens when the file does not exist, but I made sure that `test.csv` is in the root folder of my project (I am working on IntelliJ)

This code is in a scala worksheet, and the entire code looks like

```
import scala.io.Source.fromFile

object Test{

class Class1(...){...}
class Class2(...){...}

def function1(...) 
val data = fromFile("test.csv")
}
```

I am afraid that this issue is caused by IntelliJ as I tried to install Eclipse and run my code there and it seemed to work. Do you have any idea of what could cause that error to happen?

Note: The file is supposed to be read in a method of Class1 but I took it out to see if it worked outside Class1 and it turns out it doesn't

EDIT: My `test.csv`can be anywhere, as long as it works. I do not need a solution using a relative path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a text file using Relative path in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453511/how-to-read-a-text-file-using-relative-path-in-scala)

Comment: When IntelliJ compiles, or SBT as well ... the compiled sources can usually be found in `out/` or `target/`. Perhaps the file can't be found in that directory. Can you check the current directory, from which the app is invoked from?

Comment: What is the output of this? `val rootProjectDirectory = new java.io.File(".")
rootProjectDirectory.listFiles().map(_.getName).toList.foreach(println) ` If the csv file is not there, can you prove to us the file is in the directory the outputted files are in by showing a screenshot of a finder window in the root directory?

Also, instead of passing the string directly in, maybe try passing `new java.io.File("test.csv")`

Comment: @JordanCutler The csv file is indeed not there. The output of your two lines of code is `inspect.sh idea.properties`. I have no idea where these two files are

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense... You should at the very least have a build.sbt or .idea file or something. How did you initialize your IntelliJ project? Or did you just try to "Open" with IntelliJ rather than making a new project or importing?

Comment: Create folder "resources" in src/main/ . Mark this directory as resources root (right click). Keep the file in resources directory and then it should work.

Comment: I created the entire project in IntelliJ yesterday and opened it again today. By the way, I created a brand new project right now, pasted my code and I still have the same error.

Comment: @Amita Thanks for your help but that does not work either. Running the previous code about which files are in the rootProjectDirectory still returns the same output `inspect.sh` and `idea.properties`

Comment: Are you creating a project like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/2c0qbeilor6pff9/Screenshot%202018-03-13%2011.35.06.png?dl=0 and does the directory structure look like this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/3rt1ezzgjtqjsfu/Screenshot%202018-03-13%2011.35.37.png?dl=0 if not, can you show us your directory structure or give us an idea because what your project considers your root directory based on the output of the two lines of code does not make sense.

Comment: I am creating a project as you showed me. My directory structure looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/es2t9

The 'resources' directory is marked as resources directory, putting test.csv in that dir does not work either

Comment: I think I am going to reinstall IntelliJ entirely, that may work

Comment: To be honest, that may be the move. It seems something is going wrong with the way the project is set up. You can see the difference in icons of the folders/packages between mine and yours. Also, for safety, I think you should use the .scala extension rather than .sc

Comment: @JordanCutler Ok, anyway, thanks a lot for your help, kind stranger on the internet!

Comment: @H.Potter my pleasure. good luck and feel free to update me

Comment: If it's an sbt project, you can try adding the line, `resourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "/src/main/resources"` in build.sbt file and try if it works.

Comment: @JordanCutler The full reinstall of IntelliJ did not solve the problem.. I switched to Eclipse and now it is working properly. At least I can continue to learn Scala :)

Comment: Very very odd... Wish I knew why the heck it's having so much trouble